# Confused about net start/stop command

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, cmd.exe

I by mistake typed following command without service name.

```
net start
```

It responded as "These Windows services are started:"...started around 20/30 services and said command completed sucessfully. What will happen now if I type following command without service name.

```
net stop
```

Will it stop all those 20/30 services? And is there some fatal result to computer owing to stopping all these services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type `net start` without anything behind, it tells you what services are currently running ("started"). It won't actually start any service unless you put the service name behind `net start`.

If you type `net stop`, it will give you an error, because you have to tell it *what service* to stop.

[More about the NET command here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsNT/AdminTips/Network/NetCommands.html)